# Giving Photoshop for Mac a gray background like on Windows

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop

Having recently moved from Windows to Mac, the transparent application background in Photoshop for Mac is driving me a little bit bananas.  Is there a way to give the application itself a gray background like it has in Windows?

All of my searches on this topic come back with tutorials on how to add a gray background to a Photoshop file, not the application itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Window Menu > [Application Frame](http://indesignsecrets.com/cs4s-application-frame-yea-or-nea.php)

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!

Comment: Wow, was it that simple? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I switched to Mac this weekend and this was driving me insane. I can't imagine anyone using the program with the transparent background - it is so distracting!

Comment: @MaryAnn that's how gimp is set up, and it really threw me off when I started using it. You do get used to it.

Comment: Thanks that was driving me nuts.  I just made the switch to Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 Steps to do it:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. Profit.